# AG groups don't sync user DB collation change to replica servers?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability, collation

We have 2012 AG group set up between server A and server B, where A is the primary, B is the replica

1) When we changed the user DB collation on server A, on server B, the user DB still shows the old collation. Is that by design? So we would need to redo AG to make the change show on the replica servers?

2) When we change the columns and other objects' collation on server A, does that get changed automatically on the replica server through AG sync process?

3) Is there any advantage of having server collation being SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI while the DBs being Latin1_General_CI_AI ?

4) Lastly, if the default DB collation is different than SOME of the table/column collation, would that be an issue for AG/DB in general?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) When we changed the user DB collation on server A, on server B, the user DB still shows the old collation. Is that by design? So we would need to redo AG to make the change show on the replica servers?

It may show the old collation, but it's been changed. Please note that changing the collation at the database level does *not* change it on any of the items underneath until it is specifically changed, however all new items will use that by default.

If you don't trust me (I'm a random internet person!) and you have a test system you'll see that this data is cached. Change the collation, then restart the secondary replica. Now check the collation. I do not know, though, why the metadata cache is not refreshed.

> 2) When we change the columns and other objects' collation on server A, does that get changed automatically on the replica server through AG sync process?

Yes, assuming it's a database level object in a database in the AG.

> 3) Is there any advantage of having server collation being SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI while the DBs being Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI ?

Depends, does you application require a specific collation or options? The advantage is for the application to sort and display data properly.

> 4) Lastly, if the default DB collation is different than SOME of the table/column collation, would that be an issue for AG/DB in general?

It's not an issue for AGs, it's a potential issue for the application. The AG will happily send the log block changes all day.

Comment: Thank you Sean. I have changed the DB collation on the Primary server to Latin1_General_CI_AI, however, when I check the Replica servers, the DB collations are still showing the old collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI.  This is the query I used, I have also confirmed using GUI. Both replicas showing the old collation. SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases ORDER BY collation_name desc. NOTE: I have another server with the same situation, the replica server magically auto synced the db collation one day with the primary...I wish I know the reason and apply to others.

Comment: It's due to the metadata in cache not being refreshed. It does change, but you won't see it immediately though the query or gui. When the metadata for the database is flushed, it'll show the change.

Comment: Thank you Sean, are there ways to manually refresh the cache without impacting DB performance? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot speak to the Availability Group aspects of this question, I can address the Collation aspects:

> 3) Is there any advantage of having server collation being SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI while the DBs being Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI ?

First, there is no `Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` Collation. The only Collations to have "`_CP1_`" in their names are 16 of the SQL Server Collations (i.e. those having names starting with `SQL_`). The following query will show you those Collations:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() WHERE [name] LIKE N'%[_]CP1[_]%';
```

For the non-SQL Server Collations (i.e. those having a name that doesn't start with `SQL_`), you are most likely meaning one of the following two Collations:

- Latin1_General_CI_AI
- Latin1_General_100_CI_AI

You can see the full list of 52 "Latin1_General" Collations using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() WHERE [name] LIKE N'Latin1[_]General[_]%';
```

Second, not only can I *not* think of an advantage to having `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` as the Instance's default Collation while the Databases have a default Collation of either `Latin1_General_CI_AI` or `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`, I can think of some *dis*advantages, the main one being that the default Collation for `tempdb` will be `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` and so if you create temporary tables and do not specify `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` for string columns, then their Collation will very likely be different than that of the string columns in your regular Tables as well as in any Table Variables (which use the "current" Database's default Collation). This can cause issues (one's that are easy enough to work around once you find them) when doing sorts on data in temporary tables as well as when comparing string columns between regular tables / table variables and temporary tables.

Third, the SQL Server Collations (i.e. those having naming starting with `SQL_`) were deprecated with the release of SQL Server 2000. So, if at all possible, you should probably standardize on `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI` (which is the newer version of `Latin1_General_CI_AI`).

> 4) Lastly, if the default DB collation is different than SOME of the table/column collation, would that be an issue for AG/DB in general?

It is not an issue if it is what your app needs. There is a reason why each string column can have its own Collation: sometimes that is necessary. Just keep in mind that new string columns that do not specify a Collation via the `COLLATE` clause will pick up the default Collation of the Database. And some Database-level meta-data will be using the Database's default Collation, which can cause problems if comparing to string columns of a different Collation. The error you will get about a Collation conflict can be solved by specifying the `COLLATE` clause in the query / queries.

Also keep in mind that string literal and function / procedure parameters use the Database's default Collation and might behave differently than expected in certain situations. Meaning, due to Collation Precedence, comparing two parameters / literals --  `IF (@Param = 'literal')` -- might produce a different result than when comparing a column in a table with either a parameter of literal -- `WHERE alias.ColumnName = @Parameter` or `WHERE alias.ColumnName = 'literal'`. The former scenario will use the Database's default Collation while the latter scenario will use the Column's Collation.